# How to add check box checked count value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to add the  total number of check box checked count value in element.

But when i checked the check box in "heading 2" part , the count value  was added in "heading 1" part .

I did not find the issue any one please guide me resolve this issue

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gqcgwjq2/2/)

**HTMl:**

```
    <div id="main">


    <div class="a">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 cb_select_head">
                    <a data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#function-collapse"><span class=
                                    "glyphicon ecm-caret-down"></span></a><span class="labelBlock labelCounter">
                                    <span class="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span></span>
                    <span class="fb_options_head">heading 1</span>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="sidebar fb-list-option collapse in" id="function-collapse">
                    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Actuarial-collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-right"></span></a>
                      <input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c1">asdas</label>

                    </li>
                    <li class="noArrow">
                      <input id="c2" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c2">asdasd</label>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-right"></span></a>
                      <input id="c3" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c3">asdasd
                      </label>

                      <ul>
                                    <li><input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox"><label for="c1">asd 1</label></li>
                                    <li><input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox"><label for="c1">sadas 2</label></li>
                                    <li><input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox"><label for="c1">asdas 3</label></li>
                                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-right"></span></a>
                      <input id="c4" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c4">asdasd</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="noArrow">
                      <input id="c5" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c5">five</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
          <!--First List End-->

          <!--Second list start -->

             <div class="a">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 cb_select_head">
                    <a data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#function-collapse"><span class=
                                    "glyphicon ecm-caret-down"></span></a><span class="labelBlock labelCounter">
                                    <span class="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span></span>
                    <span class="fb_options_head">heading 2</span>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="sidebar fb-list-option collapse in" id="function-collapse">
                    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Actuarial-collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-right"></span></a>
                      <input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c1">asdas</label>

                    </li>
                    <li class="noArrow">
                      <input id="c2" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c2">asdasd</label>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-right"></span></a>
                      <input id="c3" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c3">asdasd
                      </label>

                      <ul>
                                    <li><input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox"><label for="c1">asd 1</label></li>
                                    <li><input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox"><label for="c1">sadas 2</label></li>
                                    <li><input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox"><label for="c1">asdas 3</label></li>
                                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-right"></span></a>
                      <input id="c4" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c4">asdasd</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="noArrow">
                      <input id="c5" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c5">five</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>  


 </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $checkboxes = $(
        '#main ul input[type="checkbox"]');
    $checkboxes.change(function() {
        var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(
            ':checked').length;
        $('.count-checked-checkboxes').text(
            countCheckedCheckboxes);
        $('#edit-count-checked-checkboxes').val(
            countCheckedCheckboxes);
    });
});
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: @j08691 : yes i changed not working updated fiddle also if u have any idea pls share

Comment: @Mgr this working for you?? https://jsfiddle.net/gqcgwjq2/5/

Answer (score 0):

see the working solution. Remember IDs needs to be unique, and avoid use of IDs whenever possible like putting input element inside the label instead of using with Id

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $checkboxes1 = $('#head1 ul input[type="checkbox"]');
  var $checkboxes2 = $('#head2 ul input[type="checkbox"]');
  $checkboxes1.change(function() {
    var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes1.filter(':checked').length;
    $('#head1 .count-checked-checkboxes').text(countCheckedCheckboxes);
  });
  $checkboxes2.change(function() {
    var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes2.filter(':checked').length;
    $('#head2 .count-checked-checkboxes').text(countCheckedCheckboxes);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="head1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 cb_select_head">
        <span class="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span>
        <span class="fb_options_head">heading 1</span>
      </div>
      <ul class="sidebar fb-list-option collapse in">
        <li>
          <label>
            <input name="cc" type="checkbox">One
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="noArrow">
          <label>
            <input name="cc" type="checkbox">Two
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <label>
                <input name="cc" type="checkbox">3 - a
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>
                <input name="cc" type="checkbox">3 -b
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>
                <input name="cc" type="checkbox">2 - c
              </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input name="cc" type="checkbox">four
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="noArrow">
          <label>
            <input name="cc" type="checkbox">five
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--First List End-->

  <!--Second list start -->

  <div class="a" id="head2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 cb_select_head">
        <span class="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span>
        <span class="fb_options_head">heading 1</span>
      </div>
      <ul class="sidebar fb-list-option collapse in">
        <li>
          <label>
            <input name="cc" type="checkbox">One
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="noArrow">
          <label>
            <input name="cc" type="checkbox">Two
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <label>
                <input name="cc" type="checkbox">3 - a
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label>
                <input name="cc" type="checkbox">3 - b
              </label>
            </li>
            <li>

              <label>
                <input name="cc" type="checkbox">2 - c
              </label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>
            <input name="cc" type="checkbox">four
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="noArrow">
          <label>
            <input name="cc" type="checkbox">five
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if [this works](https://jsfiddle.net/gqcgwjq2/10/).

Ignoring everything others have mentioned, about ID's needing to be unique and what not, I was able to tally checked boxes for each heading using DOM traversal.

I changed the jQuery to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.a').each(function(){
        var $checkboxes = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
        $checkboxes.change(function() {
           var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
        $(this).closest('.a').find('.count-checked-checkboxes').text(
            countCheckedCheckboxes);
        });
    });
});
```

1. Loop through each element '.a'
2. Use $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]'); to get just the relevant checkboxes
3. On change, traverse up the DOM until you find '.a', from there you can traverse down and find the heading class '.count-checked-checkboxes'

There's probably a better way to do this though.

.closest() starts at the current element and travels upwards looking for a match.

.find() travels downwards through descendants.

Answer (score -1):

Couple things.

j08691 is right, IDs must be unique. The browser is getting the first `#count-checked-checkboxes` and filling that value.

Also, you are getting the count for all checkboxes which is going to tally all checkboxes regardless of which `div` they are in

I would suggest the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $checkboxes = $(
        '.a ul input[type="checkbox"]');
    $checkboxes.change(function() {
        var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(
            ':checked').length;
        $('#count-checked-checkboxes-a').text(
            countCheckedCheckboxes);
        $('#edit-count-checked-checkboxes-a').val(
            countCheckedCheckboxes);
    });
});
```

But you are still getting all checkboxes. At which point I would change your second `<div class="a">` to `<div class="b">` and then duplicate the above statement like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $checkboxes = $(
        '.b ul input[type="checkbox"]');
    $checkboxes.change(function() {
        var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(
            ':checked').length;
        $('#count-checked-checkboxes-b').text(
            countCheckedCheckboxes);
        $('#edit-count-checked-checkboxes-b').val(
            countCheckedCheckboxes);
    });
});
```

And of course change your IDs to match the ones in the jquery.

https://jsfiddle.net/gqcgwjq2/28/

Comment: Yes, see the link. On another note, I always thought jQuery made document.ready obsolete as the $() syntax waits until the document is ready before firing the defined events? Am I wrong in that? Plus, it works. What gives?